# DataLore error when trying to fit an image classification model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, image-classification, datalore

I am getting this error when trying to fit my model using a datalore notebook:
I am using the GPU S Machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  at cell 7, line 24
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py, line 70, in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py, line 53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
UnimplementedError: Graph execution error: Detected at node 'sequential/conv2d/Relu' defined at (most recent call last): File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module> app.launch_new_instance() File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance app.start() File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start self.io_loop.start() File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start self.asyncio_loop.run_forever() File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever self._run_once() File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once handle._run() File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda> lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback ret = callback() File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner self.ctx_run(self.run) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run yielded = self.gen.send(value) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 358, in process_one yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 536, in execute_request self.do_execute( File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell result = self._run_cell( File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell return runner(coro) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner coro.send(None) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name, File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes if (await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy)): File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) File "<ipython-input-6-e46c72bc7443>", line 24, in <module> hist = model.fit(train_images, y[:train_size], epochs=500, batch_size=32, callbacks=[checkpointLowLoss, learning_rate_scheduler], validation_data=(val_images, val_y)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1742, in fit tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function return step_function(self, iterator) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step outputs = model.train_step(data) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1080, in train_step y_pred = self(x, training=True) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 569, in __call__ return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1150, in __call__ outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py", line 404, in call return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 512, in call return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1150, in __call__ outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler return fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 321, in call return self.activation(outputs) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/activations.py", line 321, in relu return backend.relu( File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5397, in relu x = tf.nn.relu(x) Node: 'sequential/conv2d/Relu' DNN library is not found. [[{{node sequential/conv2d/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7552]
```

This is the code:

```
# train model
hist = model.fit(train_images, y[:train_size], epochs=500, batch_size=32, callbacks=[checkpointLowLoss, learning_rate_scheduler], validation_data=(val_images, val_y))
```

There are the libraries imported:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import keras

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout, RandomRotation, RandomZoom, GlobalAveragePooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import SeparableConv2D
```

I've found on the internet that this error appears when the GPU cannot run TensorFlow

Comment: Hi @Lexy, What is the output of `train_images.shape` and `y[:train_size].shape`? Which System OS and tensorflow version are you using? This seems GPU is not setup in your system correctly. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install tensorflow with GPU support as per your system OS. Let us know if the issue still persists.